# Puppeteer page.screenshot toma imágenes en negro en el programador de tareas

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Ayuda compañeros Prpgramadores con el siguiente **codigo**:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var screenshot = require('desktop-screenshot');
    
var screenshot = require('desktop-screenshot');
    
screenshot("screenshot.png", function(error, complete) { if(error) console.log("Screenshot failed", error); else console.log("Screenshot succeeded"); });
```

Cuando ejecuto file.js localmente, se ejecuta correctamente, pero cuando lo ejecuto en el programador de tareas toma una captura de pantalla negra y no entiendo por qué.

Answer (score 1):

lo solucione, es necesario que una sesion este abierta con els mismo usuario que ejecuta la tarea, ejmeplo: en el servidor01 usuario01 inicio el servidor02 usuario01 donde se ejecuta la tarea con visualmente con el usuario01.

Comment: Genial que bueno encontraste la solución, no olvides cuando te sea posible marcar tu aporte como aceptada